# Mac hosted desktop

Tags: mac

My company is primarily a Microsoft shop, but we have an increase user base of Macs.

Because of limitations with our I.T. Department, we are looking for a hosted Mac desktop solution.

Our requirements are:

- Ability to remote control the mac  (ie RDP, VNC etc)
- Ability to install / uninstall software.  eg Adobe Reader etc
- Estimated data transfer < 1 gig per month

I've googled around with minimal success.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purchase a Mac Mini and have it co-located? [These  guys might be a great resource!](http://www.macminicolo.net)

Comment: Why would you down vote this answer??

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [MAC ec2 instances on AWS?](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/mac/)
I think this could really be useful for your case.

Comment: It is an option now, but there were no such instances 11 years ago.